# e.preventDefault(); behaviour not working in Firefox?

Tags: events, firefox, key, keydown, preventdefault

I have this basic function for handling the key event, everything works great. However, in Firefox 9.0.1 it seems I can't prevent the default event which is showing of bookmarks.

Is there any solution to prevent the default behaviour in FF?

```js
$(document).keydown(function(evt) {     
    if (evt.which == 66 && evt.ctrlKey) {                             
         if (evt.preventDefault) {
             evt.preventDefault();
         } else {
             evt.returnValue = false;
         }    
         alert("Ctrl+B pressed");
         return false;                      
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like some sort of bug regarding `alert`. Try this:

```
$(document).keydown(function(evt) {     
    if (evt.which == 66 && evt.ctrlKey) {                             
         if (evt.preventDefault) {
             evt.preventDefault();
         } else {
             evt.returnValue = false;
         }    
         console.log("Ctrl+B pressed");
         return false;                      
    }
});
```

Doesn't open the Bookmarks Toolbar for me now. I assume you don't actually want to `alert` do you? I think you can just call your method as long as it doesn't contain an `alert`.

Comment: No I don't. It works now, alert seems to abort whole client-side script. That was the reason, though it is way much better to use console.log for debugging. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why alert does that to be honest. But console.log is usually a safer bet!