# Login not working in Firefox in Meteor

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, meteor

I am trying to develop the login functionality in meteor, and I am using jade-handlebars and coffeescript.

My coffeescript  page:

```
Template.navigation.events
 "submit #login-form": (e, t) ->
    e.preventDefault()

if Meteor.userId()
  Meteor.logout()

else
  # retrieve the input field values
  email = t.find("#login-email").value
  password = t.find("#login-password").value

  # If validation passes, supply the appropriate fields to the
  # Meteor.loginWithPassword() function.
  Meteor.loginWithPassword email, password, (err) ->
    if err
     # throw new Meteor.Error(403, "Username must have at least 3 characters")
      alert "login unsucess, Please check your email and password currectly"
      console.log err
    else
      alert "sucess"
      $('#login-style').toggleClass('hide');
      console.log Meteor.userId()
      Meteor.Router.to('/')

false
```

My jade file:

```
body
  .container
    {{> Header}} 

    {{#isolate}}{{renderPage}}{{/isolate}}

template(name="Header")
  {{> navigation}}
template(name="navigation")
    {{#if currentUser}}
      {{> login}}
    {{else}}
      {{> loginout }}
    {{/if}}
```

In Chrome it works fine, but in Firefox I have to refresh my page to see the login or logout button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try returning false instead of e.preventDefault()

refer this answer as well. 
[e.preventDefault(); behaviour not working in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757301/e-preventdefault-behaviour-not-working-in-firefox)